# Error while building OpenConnect project (from official gitlab repository) for Java

Tags: openconnect

Hello i need help about building artefact for Java. I get an error when running this command for build:

`./configure --with-vpnc-script=~/Downloads/vpnc-script --with-java=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home --disable-nls`.

This is the error that i get:

`checking jni.h usability... no 
configure: error: unable to compile JNI test program`

I need your help please. I'm using release version 8.08 and building it on mac. [This is the official gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect)

[Here is the content of config.log generated](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OPIoa_N-vq4JMDVq4ouO9U-2cC_YCtKo)

Thanks

Comment: What is in the `config.log` file that should have been generated?

Comment: @Botje  [Here is the content of config.log generated](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OPIoa_N-vq4JMDVq4ouO9U-2cC_YCtKo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that configure script expects you to pass the path to the JDK's `include` directory, not the JDK itself.

This should work:

```
--with-java=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include
```

Comment: Is the output in config.log the same?

Comment: [Here is the new outup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VINPS8qH4le3GuqWPiIkHS9Ln9M3IkZk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So yes, it is complaining about missing jni_md.h. Can you try with just `--with-java` ? That should try to locate the JDK.

Comment: [Here is the new output using --with-java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mx3Ib754dlYOFgm6MXnoVwt8lQOQMO8H/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks like that configure script expects a different directory structure somehow. Symlink or copy all the headers under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin` to the directory above (`.../include`), then try again with my answer.

Comment: Great [Here is the new output using your answer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1einK-NinEDBzqMHVvQd0Ys7Chak3EiQr/view?usp=sharing). Is it good?

Comment: Looks okay, yes.

Comment: But look this, my goals is to build the jar that i can use in an android module to handle VPN connection. Can you instruct me to guide me achieve my goal please?

Comment: That is a wholly different question. Start by reading the [documentation on cross-compilation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will follow instructions over there and comme back to you if get stuck

Comment: Following the readme inside de java folder of openconnect 8.08 release, i get another mistake when running make after ./configure. Here is the error: 

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
  CC       libopenconnect_la-version.lo
  CC       libopenconnect_la-ssl.lo
In file included from ssl.c:41:
./openconnect-internal.h:102:10: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
#include <libxml/tree.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [libopenconnect_la-ssl.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Did you [install libxml2 as directed](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/building.html)?

Comment: Yes i install it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211862/discussion-between-botje-and-armel-gildas-fagbedji).

Comment: Hello, please i need your help one more time again

Comment: Ask a new question.

Comment: When i follow [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf), i get this error: `clang: error: no such file or directory: '../.libs/libopenconnect.so'
make[2]: *** [serverhash] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Need your help please

Comment: [Here is my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275196/error-when-using-the-ndk-with-other-build-systems-on-openconnect-8-08)