# Error cross-compiling openconnect-8.08 for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, openconnect

When i follow instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf), i get this error when running latest instruction that is "make":

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fasegiar/Downloads/openconnect-8.08'
  CC       libopenconnect_la-ssl.lo
In file included from ssl.c:41:
In file included from ./openconnect-internal.h:102:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1307:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ucnv.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Makefile:1037: recipe for target 'libopenconnect_la-ssl.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [libopenconnect_la-ssl.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fasegiar/Downloads/openconnect-8.08'
Makefile:749: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The TARGET that i use is: `armv7a-linux-androideabi`

My TOOLCHAIN is: `/home/fasegiar/Documents/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64`

[Here is the output of the config.log after ./configure call](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MN5rEF3vOJvrbNSs01crDfoGblZtgz4NfUvv98V-dUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please show the *full* output of your configure and make call. "Make error 1" is a useless diagnostic.

Comment: @Botje I update with full output

Comment: Is that the full output of calling configure and make? I doubt that.

Comment: Edit your question. Please add the **FULL INVOCATION AND OUTPUT OF CONFIGURE AND MAKE** not just the last few lines.

Comment: @Botje i upate my question with your need

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @Botje i update it

Comment: @Botje i find ucnv.h in /usr/include/unicode/ucnv.h, but why in compilation time it said `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ucnv.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>`  i dont understand

Comment: This is expected behavior: A cross compiler should not use files from your system, because they are not compatible! The cross compilers that come with Android only look inside the `sysroot`. Check for yourself with `./armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang -Wp,-v -fsyntax-only -x c - < /dev/null` . The configure script picked up libxml2 from your system by accident, which is why it _is_ looking at `/usr/include/libxml2`. Please read my answer and a [guide to cross compilation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the snippet you posted I can already tell you this is not going to work.
When cross-compiling you need to cross-compile *all dependencies* first for your target platform (ie Android) and then tell the configure script where to find the installed dependencies. For [openconnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/building.html) the dependencies are:

> Required:
>
> - libxml2 (this in turn requires libicu, as your error points out)
> - zlib (this is [bundled](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#zlib_compression))
> - Either OpenSSL or GnuTLS (v3.2.10+) (see [NDKPorts](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/native-dependencies-in-android-studio-40.html))
>
> Optional:
>
> - p11-kit (for PKCS#11 support)
> - libp11 (also needed for PKCS#11 support if using OpenSSL)
> - libproxy
> - trousers (for TPMv1 support if using GnuTLS)
> - libtasn1 and either tss2-esys or IBM's TPM 2.0 TSS. (for TPMv2 support if using GnuTLS)
> - libstoken (for SecurID software token support)
> - libpskc (for RFC6030 PSKC file storage of HOTP/TOTP keys)
> - libpcsclite (for Yubikey hardware HOTP/HOTP support)

Comment: Hi @Botje, i think that is what instructions under android/ folder do. But i run into this [error](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MN5rEF3vOJvrbNSs01crDfoGblZtgz4NfUvv98V-dUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: ["Note that on Android, unlike Linux, there are no separate libpthread  libraries. That functionality is included directly in libc, which does not need to be explicitly linked against."](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#core_cc) As for iconv, you will need to figure out which component drags it in.

Comment: Is that means that I need to install a libc library on my machine?

Comment: It means you may not specify `-lpthread` when linking code for android.

Comment: As it is make script that I run, I don’t find where it is specified to remove it, have you any idea please?

Comment: I find where -lpthread is, have need to not specify -liconv too?

Comment: You need to either build iconv or tell whatever dependency that needs it to not use it.